# Do we need ssl certificate for socket.io nodejs HTTPS OVER TLS?

Tags: node.js, sockets, ssl

Sorry for this question because i am not much familiar with nodejs basically i want to run my chat application on my https server but it will showing error net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE so for this we need original certificate and key or we need self created certificate ?

```
var app = require('express')();
var fs = require('fs');
var forceSsl = require('express-force-ssl');

app.use(forceSsl);
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('server.crt')
};
var server = require('https').createServer(options, app).listen(3000,function(){
        console.log("Https server started on port 3000");
});
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

So what is my main question is do we need original server.key and server.crt file or we need to create by own ?

Answer (score 0):

A TLS server always requires a certificate except for certain very unusual configurations which don't generally apply to HTTPS.

Comment: in that what should i need to do ?

Comment: Err, get a server certificate? and install it? Don't use self-signed certificates, they're not worth the paper they're printed on.

Comment: server certificate is already installed on my server this problem is occur in my socket.io request